# Updating Visual Studio and Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to update my project to .net core 2. But I am facing issues I have no option in the target framework to change to

[image]

I installed the .net core 2 sdk from the download site

[image]

I also tried the suggestion here but did not work for me

> [.NET Core 2.0 missing from my Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778942/net-core-2-0-missing-from-my-visual-studio)

But when I try to modify visual studio to install release 3 i get the following
this happens even if I click the installer and i DO NOT no why I tried various suggestions Including delete this folder

Try deleting %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages_Channels

But it does not exist on my pc I am running windows ten by the way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there is `global.json` file in your project. Try changing sdk version to 2.0.0